# coldfusion how do I unlock code programatically

Tags: coldfusion, locking

In ColdFusion the cflock tag provides a timeout in seconds.  My problem is that I want to unlock the code when certain other code is completed.  For example, I have code that says:

```
<!---need some kind of lock here --->
<!---this code is in a loop --->
<cffile action = 'append'
        file   = '#path#'/temp.cfm'
        output = '#myvariable#'>
```

Later in the program the temp file is picked up, to be combined with other information:

```
<cffile action = 'read'
        file   = '#path#/temp.cfm'
        variable = 'xyz'>
```

But I can't guess how long it will take to get from the creation of temp to the reading of it.  That may depend for example on the number of records in a MySql file, or could timeout because of slow traffic, or for other reasons.

So what I'd like to do is unlock temp after the read is completed.  In other words, I'd like a cfunlock tag, but there doesn't seem to be one.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The cflock timeout parameter does not specify how long the code can take to run, it specifies the time to wait for a lock to be provided before timing out. When the code inside your cflock block is complete, your cflock will be unlocked.

Comment: It is good to know this -- the documentation does not explain this at all.  But I do I know how much time to allow to obtain a lock?

Comment: First, I only use named locks instead of scope locks. That way my lock is specific to the work I am doing. That helps guide your choice in the time to wait. So if you need an exclusive lock on a thread that’s already running, maybe you don’t need to wait more than a second so you can bail out. But maybe you want to wait for a bunch of seconds if you only need a read lock on the same process. This might be confusing if you don’t understand read vs. exclusive locks, or threads in general.

Answer (score 2):

If the *"Later in the program"* read is actually later in the same single synchronous request as the original append/write, then you don't even need the lock, unless there is a risk of multiple concurrent requests.

If the read is in a separate request to the write, but you know the write will always start first, then you just need a `type="exclusive"` lock on the write and a `type="readonly"` lock on the read, using the same lock `name`, then the readonly lock will wait for the code in the exclusive lock to complete.

If your read might start before your write, and you know you need to wait for the first/next write state to be reached before the read would be valid, then that's when you would need to add some polling logic of your own to check whether the desired state has been reached before reading. There are many ways of achieving that - essentially after the write has completed, you could flag that state in an application variable or in your database, or rename the file after the write is complete, and then before your read code, check for the expected state in a loop and wait and check again until that state is reached, before continuing with the read.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution requires no lock. It makes use of a persistent scope, for example, request, session or application. Choose the scope appropriate to your case.

```
<!--- Placed before the file-append code --->
<cfset session.isTempFileAppendComplete=false>
...
<!---this code is in a loop --->
<cffile action = 'append'
        file   = '#path#'/temp.cfm'
        output = '#myvariable#'>
...
<!--- Placed after the file-append code --->
<cfset session.isTempFileAppendComplete=true>  

<cfif session.isTempFileAppendComplete>
    <cffile action = 'read'
            file   = '#path#/temp.cfm'
            variable = 'xyz'>    
 </cfif>
```

Comment: Although if there is a risk of concurrent requests executing the above code, then you would still need a lock to be certain - you've just moved the lock requirement from a named lock to the session scope. Eg with the above it is possible with concurrent requests that `session.isTempFileAppendComplete` could change from true to false between the `<cfif session.isTempFileAppendComplete>` check and `<cffile action = 'read'`

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but as Sev Roberts says, it does not resolve the concurrent request problem, so much as produce an error if there is one.  For this particular application I have decided to replace the temp.cfm name with a temp-datetime.cfm so that there are no conflicts.

Comment: @SevRoberts and BettyMock, I in fact thought about the possibility of concurrent requests per user-session. But, in view of "Later in the program the temp file is picked up", I thought of just a single request. In any case, to prevent concurrent access by multiple requests, just add a session lock. See my next answer.

Comment: @BettyMock, appending the date-time to the file name is a design that is fraught with difficulties. Some of the difficulties are: (1) Thread-safety is still not guaranteed. It may work for 2 or 3 requests, but will fail when there are many concurrent requests. Though request_1 may not read temp_datetime_1.cfm while the file is being appended, nothing will stop the request from reading temp_datetime_2.cfm. (2) The design is inefficient. To correctly implement it, each request will have to keep track of the datetime of a file. Which is too much (unnecessary) responsibility for a request.

Comment: @BKBK Thank you for your thoughts about date-time stamps and concurrency. You are quite right that there could be a conflict between time 1 and time 2, unless steps are taken to avoid that.  It seems to me this might be just one line of code. I do expect a very low volumn of concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

If there are going to be multiple concurrent users, with the possibility of each having multiple concurrent requests, then use an application-scoped or a named lock. However, I assume a single concurrent user.
To avoid concurrent requests, add session locks (not named locks, as these are in application scope):

```
<cflock timeout = "10" scope = "session" type = "exclusive"> 
    <cfset session.isTempFileAppendComplete=false>
</cflock>

...

<cflock timeout = "600" scope = "session" type = "exclusive"><!---decide on timeout estimate --->
    <!---this code is in a loop --->
    <cffile action = 'append'
            file   = '#path#'/temp.cfm'
            output = '#myvariable#'>
</cflock>

...

<cflock timeout = "600" scope = "session" type = "exclusive">
    <!--- Placed after the file-append code --->
    <cfset session.isTempFileAppendComplete=true>  
</cflock>

<cflock timeout = "60" scope = "session" type = "readOnly">
    <cfif session.isTempFileAppendComplete>
        <cffile action = 'read'
                file   = '#path#/temp.cfm'
                variable = 'xyz'>    
     </cfif>
</cflock>
```